# Receiving undefined constant error in a Drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal-7

I am getting this error in a Drupal module:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DA_REGION_US_ALUMNI - assumed 'DA_REGION_US_ALUMNI' in _da_core_hierarchy_region_list() (line 249 of /home/daweb_dev/democratsabroad/drupal/sites/all/modules/custom/da_core/includes/country-data.inc)

The offending bit of code looks like this:

```
function _da_core_hierarchy_region_list() {
  $regions = array(
    ''  => '- select region -',
    DA_REGION_US_ALUMNI => 'US/Friends/Alumni',
    DA_REGION_AMERICAS => 'Americas',
    DA_REGION_EMEA => 'EMEA',
    DA_REGION_AP => 'Asia/Pacific',
  );
  return $regions;
}
```

The DA_REGION_US_ALUMNI constant was added to already existing code that was running okay. I cannot see any difference between that the DA_REGION_US_ALUMNI and the other entries so do not know why it is being flagged as undefined.

Comment: I have found another module that has the define statements so this can be consider answered

Answer (score 0):

This statement was in an includes file. There was a module up directory level that had the define statements

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether constants are defined in same file or not i.e. in "country-data.inc" at following location (/home/daweb_dev/democratsabroad/drupal/sites/all/modules/custom/da_core/includes/country-data.inc).

This issues generally came when constants are defined in some other file.